# Arena-based allocation library for C++ or tutorial

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm writing a C++ BVH (Bounding Volume Hierarchy) tree following the example of the BVH implemented in Physcally Based Rendering 3 ([Github](https://github.com/mmp/pbrt-v3/tree/master)), which uses an Arena-based allocation to improve the performance.

Although their implementations works perfectly, I was interested in comparing their MemoryArena structure with other good implementations out there.

Any recommended libraries (or tutorials) of this kind of structure?.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has a good article [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/arenas) that talks about everything from Why Use Arena-based Allocation to Usage Patterns and Best Practices. It is written for their Protocol Buffers, but has a lot of good information.

Comment: Today someone recommended me another article related to this topic. So I will leave here the [link](https://blog.molecular-matters.com/2012/08/14/memory-allocation-strategies-a-linear-allocator/)